# internal time shinyproxy UTC

Tags: r, shinyproxy

I successfully deployed an application with `shiny` and `shinyproxy`.
The purpose of the app is to manually review an algorithm decision

We want to store not only the decision but also the timestamp in which the decision is made, so inside the code we are making use of `Sys.time()`.
Our current time zone is UTC+2 while inside the app when deployed with shinyproxy it seems that `Sys.time` will give us UTC time ( so 2 hours behind what we'd like to see).
I checked the server date and it's ok.

Is there some configuration we can modify on shinyproxy to deal with this situation? Or it's easier to work on some parameters of `Sys.time()` or another R function, i suppose specifying something like `timezone="Europe/Amsterdam"`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
d <- Sys.time()
d
[1] "2020-07-03 11:51:22 BST"
lubridate::with_tz(d, tzone="EST")
[1] "2020-07-03 05:51:22 EST"
```